# Magento 2 - dynamically update the currency symbol

Tags: magento2, currency-symbol

I am trying to dynamically update the currency symbol (based on a users custom customer attribute).
I have a plugin afterGetCurrency which is loading correctly, and I can get the current symbol but how do I override it?

```
<?php
namespace Sulman\MyModule\Plugin;

class CurrencySymbolSwitch
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Currency $result
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterGetCurrency(
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency $subject,
        $result,
        $currency
    ) {
        var_dump($result->getSymbol()); // this is working
        // but how do I change it?
        $result->setSymbol('O'); // Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Currency::setSymbol()
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I don't want to change the currency, just change the symbol.

Any ideas? Thanks